# How do I get the string data type to work in a class?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and am currently working on a project that wants me to turn a Roman Numeral into a Hindu-Arabic number (our normal number system). I'm currently writing a class RomanNumeralType which needs to store a roman numeral type string. When I try to run the code below I get error code C3646: unknown override specifier and also error codes C4430 and C2061 which both address string (in bold) not being a valid identifier. It was my impression that #include  fixed this however I am unsure why it is not working. I currently do not have a function that actually converts the numeral to a number but I want to fix this problem first. How do I get the string data type to work in my class?

Here is a minimally reproduced example of my code

```
//main
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Header2.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string ans;

    cout << "Please enter a string of Roman Numerals (M,D,C,L,X,V,I): " << endl; 
    cin >> ans;
    }

    RomanNumeralType r1(ans);

    cout << "Your original Roman Numeral was: " << r1.getNumeral() << endl;

    cout << "Your Roman Numeral as a integer is: " << r1.getNumber(r1.getNumeral()) << endl;

    return 0;
}

//Header2.h

#ifndef HEADER2
#define HEADER2
#include <string>

class RomanNumeralType {
    public:

        **string** romanNumeral;

        RomanNumeralType(**string** x)

        {romanNumeral = x;}

        **string** getNumeral()

        {return romanNumeral;}

}
```

Comment: Within the header, give `string` its fully qualified (unambiguous) name  i.e.   `std::string`.   If you also do that in `main()`, the using directive (`using namespace std`) is not needed - and quite a few people prefer that.

Comment: what does #include <string> do?

Comment: `#include <string>` will mean that your translation unit sees declarations for `std::string` and some related functionality. It doesn't mean that it will automatically convert the unqualified name `string` to the qualified name `std::string`. As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) gets into, many programmers prefer being explicit about which identifiers come from which namespaces, especially in the case of the C++ standard library.

Answer (score -1):

When you do `#include <string>` think of it as though you are pasting in the contents of a file shared across all developers that has all the definitions for `string`. That class lives within the `std` namespace, so when you want to use a `string`, you have to tell the compiler that `string` is in `std`. The preferred method is to use the fully qualified name, so every time you use `string`, you would replace it with `std::string`.

The other option is to do what you did in `main.cpp`, `using namespace std;`This tells the compiler that the namespace to look in is in `std`. This is generally considered bad practice for actual programs, but it is OK if it is a small, one off program like you seem to be writing.

If you do the first option, you will have to change everything in the `std` namespace such as `cout`, but it is clearer that you didn't write your own.

Comment: A using directive like `using namespace std` in a header file is considered VERY bad practice in C++.   If you do a search here (or online more generally) it is pretty easy to find explanations about why it is bad practice.   Doing that in a single compilation unit (like main.cpp, in this example) is not as bad a practice, but it is not exactly good practice either.